# Mastercard contactless track (bit) 35 ISO8583 assembling

Tags: contactless-smartcard, iso8583, jpos, mastercard

I am creating a function in our application to manage the field (bit) 35 in ISO8583 for **contactless** transactions.

I have to create the ISO8583 fields and I don't know how to assemble the bit 35 for contactless transactions with CHIP or MAGNETIC BAND.

The main question is if someone has an example of service tracks 35 for MasterCard Contacless.

I have an example like of the image but the SERVICE CODE belongs to a CHIP EMV transaction (not contactless). In this case the SERVICE CODE is 201.

[MasterCard example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT3Zf.png)

In Wikipedia it shows a rule but it is not much easy to understand:

So I want to know if the **SERVICE CODE** for a CONTACTLESS transaction is other number different to **201**.

Thanks.

Comment: Joana, you forgot to hide PAN from Track example.

Comment: Hi @iso8583.infosupport . It is a testing card. It is not in the market. 
Thanks for the suggestion and I will try to not show again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot recognize Contactless MasterCard card from Service Code.

MasterCard Service Codes may start from 1xx, 2xx, 5xx, 6xx.

Service code on Track1/Track2 can be different from service code Tag value or at Track data of card application.

Also keep in mind that for Contactless-Swipe profiles Discretionary Data of Track2 contains Dynamic CVC value.

For detailed Service code requirements I can point you to "M/Chip Requirements—For Contact and Contactless" which you may find in internet easily.